# is this always identity matrix?

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

do you think the following matrix multiplication results in I?

$R(R^TR)^{-1}R^T$= I   or diag(I, O)

R is not necessarily  square and may not have an inverse.

Comment: $R^T R$ may not have an inverse, so nope.

Comment: h sorry I made a small mistake. by matrix I, i mean identity plus some zeros in the down corner: diag(I, O)

Comment: You should post another question because this edit drastically changed the meaning. Link to this one as a follow-up.

Answer (score 5):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) noting that $R^\dagger = (R^T R)^{-1} R^T$ is the pseudoinverse we see that
$$RR^\dagger = I \text{ iff } R\in\mathbb R^{m\times n} \text{ and } \mathrm{rank}(R) = n$$

---

In general it is false though, see this counter-example:
Let $R = \pmatrix{1 & 0}$ then
$$R (R^T R)^{-1} R^T$$
doesn't exist because the inverse of
$$R^T R = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$$
doesn't exist. Especially it can't be equal to $I$.

---

Assuming existence of $(R^T R)^{-1}$ we can write
$$I = (R^T R)^{-1} R^T R \Rightarrow R = R (R^T R)^{-1} R^T R$$
but this does *NOT* imply that
$$R (R^T R)^{-1} R^T = I$$
because $R$ will not be invertible in general. We do know though that
$$ R^T R (R^T R)^{-1} R^T = R^T$$

Comment: For that example you could even use $R = (0)$ and then it's kind of trivial that it doesn't work. What about when $(R^T R)^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: @Murp Lol that didn't come to my mind :D Nice remark! I'll check on the existence part.

Answer (score 2):

1. If $R$ is square, then $R^TR$ is invertible exactly when $R$ has full rank, i.e. is invertible.  In this case the claimed identity is true.
2. If $R$ is $m\times n$, then $R^TR$ and its inverse is $n\times n$, and $R(R^TR)^{-1}R^T$ is $m\times m$.  If $m>n$, then this can never equal the identity, since the rank of the expression is at most $n$.